# Background color (colorWithPatternImage) not filling entire view for iPad

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, background-color, uicolor

I am trying to set the background color with a checkered image I have. I am currently using this in my iPhone app and now am trying to create a universal app. When I use this:

```
 UIImage *bgimg = [UIImage imageNamed:@"square_bg.png"];
 self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:bgimg];
```

It works fine for my iPhone app. When it loads on the iPad in portrait mode, there is about 20px worth of white space at the bottom. When it loads in landscape, it is fine. If I rotate from portrait to landscape, then back again, it is also fine.

What am I missing that will fill the pattern all the way to the bottom of my view?

**Update**

If I set the color to a solid color, [UIColor blueColor], the entire screen fills in correctly. So why the discrepancy from colorWithPatternImage and a solid color?

**Update 2**

The file I am using is a PNG file with dimensions of 252x230. I've used this image to make patterns in the iPhone version of this app with no issues. I'm not sure if the file size or dimensions have any bearing on this issue, but I thought I would put it out there just in case.

Comment: Core Graphics will draw your pattern image starting from the bottom-left corner of the view. Can you test using a pattern image with borders to see if the image is getting 1) clipped, or 2) margin added?

Comment: I'll give that a try and let you know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

20px sounds like the status bar height. Could you tell us the view frame?

Is your autoresizing set correctly to dynamic width & height and fixed borders?

Comment: I kinda feel like an idiot. I went back to check all of the dimensions, and the status bar was set on for this view, causing a 20px shift in things. When I turned off the status bar, everything fills in correctly. Still curious why it wouldn't affect it in Landscape mode. But the issue is resolved.

Comment: I think it is connected with autoresizing. I had similar issues with a navigation controller and its navigation bar. Also worked correctly when started in landscape or after first rotation.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps the view is not set to the correct height.  If you change backgroundColor to a solid color will it fill the entire screen?

Comment: Yes, it does. If I swap out colorWithPatternImage with blueColor, I get a full screen of blue, no issues.