# App display fine in iphone 4s,but background will not set in iphone 5

Tags: iphone, ios

I have developed an app .In that app I am setting background image, it will display fine in iPhone 4s but background image not set in iPhone 5.

This is my screen in iPhone 4s

[image]  [image]

And it display like this in iPhone 5:

[image]   [image]

And I am using this code to set background image:

```
// Custom initialization
        self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"inner-bg"]];
        bgView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"login-bg"]];
        bgView.layer.cornerRadius =7;
        bgView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
```

Comment: same image will not work on both iphone. you need two different images for different resolution screens....

Comment: yes, i have two image one in login-bg and login-bg2x

Comment: you also need to add login-bg-568h@2x.png in your resources and also need check iPhone4 or 5, then set image accordingly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can add a -568h@2x image,

[image]

or you can [stretch the original one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10629692/889538).

Comment: and what for the control that puts in interface builder, its also not display at proper place in iphone 5,but display great in iphone 4

Comment: @aron For nib file, you can create a retina one. Newest Xcode supports this.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have `inner-bg-568h.png` and `inner-bg-568h@2x.png` versions of your images?

The iPhone 5's larger screen requires different sized images to display correctly in the view.

Comment: yes i have two image  inner-bg.png (size 320*480) and inner-bg@2x.png (640*960) is that right,and do i have to put -568h in image name?

Comment: and what for the control that puts in interface builder, its also not display at proper place in iphone 5,but display great in iphone 4