# UIColor colorWithPatternImage with increasing offset

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicolor, cashapelayer

I am asynchronously downloading a list of square images where each of them represents some color or pattern.

Let's say for example this square (even though you'll see only a triangle, the other part is white):

[image: pattern image]

My goal is to make these images round and clickable so I am using a private library `MCColorPicker` which expects an array of `UIColor` and then for each element of this array creates a new subclass of `CAShapeLayer` class. New UIColor for downloaded image is created with `colorWithPatternImage`

```
convertedColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:image];
```

The problem is that each subsequent `UIColor` image has an offset from the previous one and only the first few ones fit in the circle.

[image]

I cannot understand why do they move for a few points for each new color. Do you have and idea where could be a problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I've solved this issue with [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14996324/1092167). It was necessary to fit the images in the center as they were drawn one after other one.